# python mutagen eyed3 write id3v1 tag

Tags: python, mutagen, eyed3

I am using mutagen to manipulate my mp3's but I am finding it hard to write id3v1 tags using this, looks like the popular eyed3 package also doesnt not give any examples on how to do this. Can anyone who has worked on mutagen and eyed3 give me suggestions on how to write id3v1 tags to an mp3 file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial
The comments at Oct 4 2011 give a bit explanation how to save those tags.

Is this what you're looking for?